# is it possible to run through spark-submit without python modules in executors?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, python-module, spark-submit

I have a cluster of 7 nodes.
1: master
2: nn1
3: nn2
4: dn1
5: dn2
6: dn3
7: gn

I only installed python modules in gateway node.
And I ran a python code through spark-submit.

below is my code

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
import pandas as pd

# Spark configuration
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("uber-date-trips")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

# data parsing
lines = sc.textFile( "/user/tester/trips_2020-03.csv" )
header = lines.first()
filtered_lines = lines.filter(lambda row:row != header)

# data filtering and counting same date data
dates = filtered_lines.map(lambda x: x.split(",")[2].split(" ")[0])
result = dates.countByValue()

# save the result to csv type
pd.Series(result, name="trips").to_csv("trips_date.csv")
```

I thought this job would be failed.
because there weren't python modules in executors(dn1, dn2, dn3).

But this job was success.

Is there anybody to explain to me?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, can you share your spark-submit parameter settings?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.